# Linear space data-structure supporing subsequence query on a static string

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, subsequence

Build a data-stucture from a given string **S** of length **n** which supports fast queries for checking whether an input string **J** of length **m** is a subsequence of **S**.

**S** is a static string and pre-processing time of the data-structure can be ignored.

---

#### Requirements:

- The space consumption should be linear `O(n)`
- The runtime of `subsequence(J)` should depend on **m** - not necessarily `O(m)` but, the faster the better.

#### What is subsequence?

**A** is a subsequence of **B** if **A** can be constructed by removing zero or more characters from **B**. I.e `ABA` is a subsequence of `ADBDBAC`

#### What I tried

A data-structure which supports the `Subsequence(J)` query stores pointers from each letter in **S** to the next occurrence in **S** of every letter in the alphabet.

Let **A** be an array of length **n + 1**. **A** contains hash-tables hashed over alphabet, **σ**. Each key-value pair **(k,v)** in the hash-table contains some letter **k** as key and it's next occurrence as value **v**.

- The hash-table **A_0** contains the first occurrence of every letter in the alphabet.
- The hash-table **A_1** contains the index of second occurrence for the letter at **S_0** along with the first occurrence of the other letters.
- The hash-table **A_2** contains the index of second occurrence for the letters **S_1** and **S_2** assuming they are different letters - otherwise **A_2** will contain the third index of the letter at **S_1** - along with the first occurrence of the other letters and so on...

Example: If **T** is `B C A D F B`, **¥** represents the hashtable **A_0** and represents a **Ø** null pointer, the data-structure would look like:

 `|0 1 2 3 4 5
 |¥ B C A D B
A|3 3 3 Ø Ø Ø
B|1 5 5 5 5 Ø
C|2 2 Ø Ø Ø Ø
D|4 4 4 4 Ø Ø`

The alphabet **\sigma** is built from the letters in **T** and is static. Therefore, perfect hashing (FKS) can be used.

Running the query

To perform the `Subsequence(J)` query with the string **J**, we lookup the **A**-index of the first occurrence **J_0** in **S** using **A_0**.

In the example we could query `Subsequence("BAB")` to test if `BAB` is a subsequence:
* look-up `B` in column 0 which returns index 1
* look-up `A` in column 1 which returns index 3
* look-up `B` in column 3 which returns index 5

As long as we don't pass a null-pointer, the string is subsequence. The hash-lookups take constant time and we have to perform at most **|J|** of them the runtime is **O(|J|)**.

The space consumption is **O(|J|·|S|)**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Is the size of the alphabet constant?

Comment: @wp78de My bad, first time poster - I've taken a look at the docs and added a what did I try section.

Comment: @pkpnd yes, the string **S** is given before we build the datastructure.

Comment: @DannyDannyDanny That's not what I asked. How many different letters are there? Could S contain all different characters, no matter how long S is?

Comment: Ah, well, there is no restriction on what makes up **S**. However, considering we only start building the datastructure once **S** is given, one could say that the alphabet size is the number of unique letters in **S**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and slow way to check whether or not **J** is a subsequence of **S** is:

1. Start at the beginning of **S**
2. For each character **c** in **J**, in order, move forward in **S** to the next occurrence of **c**.
3. Iff you make it to the end and find a match for every character, then **J** is a subsequence of **S**.

You can accelerate these searches by building a map from each character that occurs in **S** to a sorted array of the positions at which that character occurs.

Then, to find the next occurrence of a character in step (2), you can lookup the position array for that character and do a binary search in the array for the next occurrence after the current position.

Total worst-case complexity to do a subsequence check would be **O(m log n)**.

Comment: Thanks, your idea was a big help and pointed me in the right direction. I found an improved method that maps to Y-fast-tries instead of sorted arrays. This gives a time complexity of **O(m log log n)**.

Comment: @pkpnd not so - you don't need to use an array for the character -> positions map, and you don't need to store positions for characters that don't appear.